# Why is touring Japan a big deal?

Tags: band

This is a question to all the rockers but why is touring Japan seen as such a big milestone in a band's career? Is it often just that it is a bands first big tour outside their home country or is there more to it than that?

Comment: I always thought it was a joke a la Spinal Tap.

Comment: This is an interesting read on the subject, though it is specific to Jazz in this article. http://www.iwasdoingallright.com/jazz-blog/165/

Comment: This seems like more of a question for [Music Fans](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Japan is one of the biggest markets for western music. Even bands not well known in the west sell acceptable amounts of units in Japan...

Especially Rock-Music but as well Folk-Music (ethno - folklore)

Comment: In that case is it such a big deal?

Comment: Well, if you are on stage at home with 50 people in the audience of which 49 are family and friends and one, who just happened to chose the wrong concert-hall - you will definitely be impressed when you're standing in front of thousands of japs who go totally crazy when you're playing the only 2-chord-riff you know on your guitar... ;-) -> This actually happened to a friend of mine - it's his excuse now for not having to learn new chords :-) (I made this one up)

Answer (score 0):

We just been over there playing Tokyo for a week. Its such an impressive place, and it being so "exotic" to us westerners, its certainly something you want in your bands CV.

The problems we experienced were, that we had minimal merch sales - following a DIY approach, coming from Scotland. Also there were  no payouts as even the local bands had to buy-in(!) To the local shows, sometimes only having 20 folk showing up.

We loved the hospitality and the culture shock, but if you want to earn some bucks, it will take a bit of effort to pull it off.

An experience of a lifetime nevertheless!